# how to modify the query to get monthly attendence report using asp.net c# with Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datatables

i have a table in sql server like as follows

```
rollno   date           atendence
  1      05/27/2015       1
  2      05/27/2015       0
  3      05/27/2015       1
  4      05/27/2015        1
  1      04/27/2015        1
  2      04/27/2015        1
  3      04/27/2015        1
  4      04/27/2015        1
```

in the above table in atendence column 1 indicates present and 0 indicates absent

when i am trying to display atendence report for month wise i am able to calculate total report not monthly wise..

i used the following query

```
    select rollno,  sum(case when satendence.atendence != 0  then satendence.atendence else 0 end)
as atendence, (select count(day) from atenmaster) as total,
(convert (money, 100.0 * sum(case when satendence.atendence != 0  then satendence.atendence else 0 end) / (select count(day) from atenmaster), 1)) as percentage
from satendence 
group by rollno
```

the output for the above query is as follows

```
rollno     atendence   total      percentage

  1           2          2         100.00
  2            1          2          50.00
  3            2          2         100.00
 4             2         2          100.00
```

but i want to display it as follows

```
_____________________________________________________________________
                 April                          may
______________________________________________________________________
rollno    atendence    total     percentage   atendence total percentage
_________________________________________________________________________
1           1           1         100.00         1          1     100.00
2           1            1         100.00        0           1    0.00
3           1            1         100.00        1           1     100.00
________________________________________________________________________
```

using asp.net grid view.

Answer (score 0):

First confirm if `iTextSharp` DLL is added to the `dll` references in your project and then make sure you are including the proper namespaces in your code. An examlpe would be :

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

Just make sure all this is properly referenced in your project as well as in code. If not, you need to add references for `iTextSharp`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the iTextSharp is available in your web server where the website is hosted.

> Move or copy the iTextSharp.dll into the GAC -  c:\windows\assembly - in your web server

Answer (score 0):

Have you published your application? See what error message says. Put iTextSharp.dll into your bin folder of your Web Server. Moving it into GAC is not a good approach as not all applications require this DLL.

Comment: @Daniel Groh... Already I moved my dll file into bin folder and it is perfectly working in my local server...i am getting this error when i upload that into a website...

Comment: @user3567786 please I would suggest you to exactly explain your scenario. it doesn't seem clear for us I guess. Your post does not mention any upload funcionality

Comment: Maybe this is too short as an answer, but nevertheless @DanielGroh is right. The answer to the question is as trivial as described in his answer. I wouldn't know how to answer it otherwise. You should deploy iTextSharp on your web server *in the same way you deploy any other third party DLL*.